# How to properly use collection factories in scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, implicit, scala-collections

Something like this:

```
implicit class PairOps[A, B, C[X] <: Iterable[X]](val c: C[(A,B)]) extends AnyVal {
   def swap = c.map { case (a, b) => (b, a) } 
}
```

Kinda works ... except that `val foo: Seq[(Int, String)]  = Seq(("foo",1)).swap`  does not compile, because `swap` returns `Iterable` rather than a `Seq`.

How do I fix it? There used to be `breakOut` in 2.12 that was using some magic (that I never quite understood tbh) to do this kind of thing ... but now I need a `Factory` ...

Tried adding it as an implicit param:

```
   def swap(implicit f: Factory[(B,A),C]) = c.map { case (a,b) => (b,a) }.to(f) }
```

This compiles with the right type, but I can't use it, because I don't have that implicit in scope at the call site (even `swap(Seq)` does't work for some reason, even though `swap.to(Seq)` does (in the first version, without implicit factory) ...

Can someone please set me straight here? There must be a way to accomplish what I want here, but I can't figure out the right incantation :(

Comment: the whole thing is a bit messy, check: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html#transforming-any-collection

Comment: Does it compile for you? When I test it I need `implicit f: Factory[(B,A), C[(B, A)]]` - see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/YvZt9j6US1KBCqR08KNsMQ/2

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yeah, that works, thanks. Looks like I was close, but not quite there :) This seems awfully verbose if I was two write like 20 of these extension methods :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is modifying the implicit you are fetching:

```
import scala.collection.Factory

implicit class PairOps[A, B, C[X] <: Iterable[X]](val c: C[(A,B)]) extends AnyVal {
   def swap(implicit f: Factory[(B, A), C[(B, A)]]) = c.map { case (a, b) => (b, a) }.to(f)
}

List(1 -> "test").swap
```

see [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/YvZt9j6US1KBCqR08KNsMQ/2)

The reason for the verbosity is that *ask for `[A, C[_]]` and make `C[A]` out of it* approach which was used prior to 2.13 doesn't work if you want to do e.g.

```
Factory[(Int, String), Map[Int, String]]
```

(You can check that in 2.12 when you use `.to(Map)` (e.g with scala-collection-compat) you'll end up with a Map... upcasted to `Iterable[(K, V)]` precisely because `.to` interface operates on `[A, Coll[_]]` and to be able to shove `Map` factory there, it has to upcast it to `Iterable` factory.)

In other words the verbosity added by by 2.13 allows `Factory` to be used in cases like `seq.map(a => a -> a.toString).to(Map)` which eliminated the need for `CanBuildFrom` and separate syntax for `.to[Coll]` and `.toMap`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a slightly less verbose way to do this: turns out that `Iterable` _knows_ its `iterableFactory`, so instead of declaring it as implicit parameter, I can just do `def f: coll.iterableFactory`

Answer (score 2):

Took me a bit of fiddling around and to be very honest I'm not 100% sure of *why* this works (and if anyone comes along with an explanation you should probably accepts their answer), but it looks like this gets the job done:

```
implicit class PairOps[A, B, C[X]](val c: C[(A, B)]) extends AnyVal {
  def swap(implicit ev: C[(A, B)] <:< collection.IterableOnceOps[(A, B), C, _]): C[(B, A)] =
    c.map(_.swap)
}
```

The returned type is the one of the collection wrapped by `PairOps`. You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/Yn6tYWBsRpCQri2CNRhwPw).

Comment: One decade using Scala and that `<:<` still escapes me. I'll do some reading and see if I can understand my own code. :-)

Comment: Yeah ... I don't understand it either :D. I think, I'll go Mateusz's suggestion in the comments – that one I at least understand (almost). Also, it is a bit shorter. Funny, I tried to move the `ev` to class level (removing anyval of course) in attempt to make it less verbose when there's a ton of these little extensions ... and it doesn't compile that way :/

Comment: I guess you can write a type alias which would turn `MyFactory[A, C]` into `Factory[A, C[A]]` where needed, it won't solve the verbosity issue but make it more bearable.